# How to get the IDs of a cluster of nodes in a network using igraph in R?

Tags: r, igraph

I have an edge list that is in the following format:

```
# A tibble: 162,157 x 4
      id source target weight
   <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>
 1     1      2    166   3777
 2     2      2    204  17527
 3     3      2    279    999
 4     4      2    373   6826
 5     5      2    552   1313
 6     6      2    664    680
 7     7      2    670   7624
 8     8      2    791    167
 9     9      2   1015     99
10    10      2   1182  18716
# … with 162,147 more rows
```

I have created a graph from this data using `igraph::graph_from_data_frame(df, directed=TRUE)` and have plotted the results, which can be seen in the following image.

[image: network.png]

The plot was generated with the following code snippet.

```
ggraph(g) +
    geom_node_point(size=0.6) +
    theme_graph()
```

What I would like to do is figure out which nodes are in the 6 tiny clusters surrounded by whitespace. I realize that I could assign labels, but in this instance that would be impossible to read. Is there a more mathematical or programmatic approach to identifying what those nodes are using igraph?

Comment: How did you get this plot? Did you simply write `plot(g)` or did you do something more specific?

Comment: @G5W - I used `ggraph` and have updated the question to show the full code that I used.

Comment: `g2 <- igraph::max_cliques(g)` will extract all complete sub-graphs from the graph. Then something like `lapply(g2, names)` will tell you the node names (if present) in each sub-graph.

Comment: @neilfws  Is max_cliques going to work with 162,000 nodes?

Comment: @G5W Don't know. Perhaps they could devise some filter first if they have some idea of sub-graph sizes. I just realised: as there are no edges in the plot, we can't see if those clusters are connected or not. If they are, we would want to look at community detection, not sub-graphs.